# (Buildroot) How to load modules automatically

Tags: kernel-modules, buildroot

I'd like to load some additional modules at boot.

This works fine from the command line:

```
modprobe -a i2c-dev
modprobe -a snd-soc-pcm512x
modprobe -a snd-soc-wm8804
```

But I want this done at boot. I've tried creating /etc/modules, /etc/modprobe.conf and /etc/modprobe.d/i2c-dev.conf, etc. with the module name in there, but no luck.

I'm using a buildroot-2017-08, which I believes uses kmod, with a BusyBox init.

I can just create an init.d script, but I think there's a specific location that should contain the list of modules to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find many polished and ready scripts. Turns out that Linux From Scratch (LFS) had some scripts that look good and are easy to use.

My solution to loading modules for a plain BusyBox init:

**/etc/init.d/S02modules**

```
#!/bin/sh
########################################################################
#
# Description : Module auto-loading script
#
# Authors     : Zack Winkles
#
# Version     : 00.00
#
# Notes       :
#
########################################################################

. /etc/sysconfig/functions

# Assure that the kernel has module support.
[ -e /proc/ksyms -o -e /proc/modules ] || exit 0

case "${1}" in
    start)

        # Exit if there's no modules file or there are no
        # valid entries
        [ -r /etc/sysconfig/modules ] &&
            egrep -qv '^($|#)' /etc/sysconfig/modules ||
            exit 0

        boot_mesg -n "Loading modules:" ${INFO}

        # Only try to load modules if the user has actually given us
        # some modules to load.
        while read module args; do

            # Ignore comments and blank lines.
            case "$module" in
                ""|"#"*) continue ;;
            esac

            # Attempt to load the module, making
            # sure to pass any arguments provided.
            modprobe ${module} ${args} >/dev/null

            # Print the module name if successful,
            # otherwise take note.
            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                boot_mesg -n " ${module}" ${NORMAL}
            else
                failedmod="${failedmod} ${module}"
            fi
        done < /etc/sysconfig/modules

        boot_mesg "" ${NORMAL}
        # Print a message about successfully loaded
        # modules on the correct line.
        echo_ok

        # Print a failure message with a list of any
        # modules that may have failed to load.
        if [ -n "${failedmod}" ]; then
            boot_mesg "Failed to load modules:${failedmod}" ${FAILURE}
            echo_failure
        fi
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: ${0} {start}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

Based on this LFS script:
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.5/scripts/apds05.html

**/etc/sysconfig/functions**

```
#!/bin/sh
#######################################################################
#
# Description : Run Level Control Functions
#
# Authors     : Gerard Beekmans - gerard@linuxfromscratch.org
#
# Version     : 00.00
#
# Notes       : With code based on Matthias Benkmann's simpleinit-msb
#        http://winterdrache.de/linux/newboot/index.html
#
########################################################################

## Environmental setup
# Setup default values for environment
umask 022
export PATH="/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin"

# Signal sent to running processes to refresh their configuration
RELOADSIG="HUP"

# Number of seconds between STOPSIG and FALLBACK when stopping processes
KILLDELAY="3"

## Screen Dimensions
# Find current screen size
if [ -z "${COLUMNS}" ]; then
    COLUMNS=$(stty size)
    COLUMNS=${COLUMNS##* }
fi

# When using remote connections, such as a serial port, stty size returns 0
if [ "${COLUMNS}" = "0" ]; then
    COLUMNS=80
fi

## Measurements for positioning result messages
COL=$((${COLUMNS} - 8))
WCOL=$((${COL} - 2))

## Provide an echo that supports -e and -n
# If formatting is needed, $ECHO should be used
case "`echo -e -n test`" in
    -[en]*)
        ECHO=/bin/echo
        ;;
    *)
        ECHO=echo
        ;;
esac

## Set Cursor Position Commands, used via $ECHO
SET_COL="\\033[${COL}G"      # at the $COL char
SET_WCOL="\\033[${WCOL}G"    # at the $WCOL char
CURS_UP="\\033[1A\\033[0G"   # Up one line, at the 0'th char

## Set color commands, used via $ECHO
# Please consult `man console_codes for more information
# under the "ECMA-48 Set Graphics Rendition" section
#
# Warning: when switching from a 8bit to a 9bit font,
# the linux console will reinterpret the bold (1;) to
# the top 256 glyphs of the 9bit font.  This does
# not affect framebuffer consoles
NORMAL="\\033[0;39m"         # Standard console grey
SUCCESS="\\033[1;32m"        # Success is green
WARNING="\\033[1;33m"        # Warnings are yellow
FAILURE="\\033[1;31m"        # Failures are red
INFO="\\033[1;36m"           # Information is light cyan
BRACKET="\\033[1;34m"        # Brackets are blue

STRING_LENGTH="0"   # the length of the current message

#*******************************************************************************
# Function - boot_mesg()
#
# Purpose:      Sending information from bootup scripts to the console
#
# Inputs:       $1 is the message
#               $2 is the colorcode for the console
#
# Outputs:      Standard Output
#
# Dependencies: - sed for parsing strings.
#            - grep for counting string length.
#
# Todo:
#*******************************************************************************
boot_mesg()
{
    local ECHOPARM=""

    while true
    do
        case "${1}" in
            -n)
                ECHOPARM=" -n "
                shift 1
                ;;
            -*)
                echo "Unknown Option: ${1}"
                return 1
                ;;
            *)
                break
                ;;
        esac
    done

    ## Figure out the length of what is to be printed to be used
    ## for warning messages.
    STRING_LENGTH=$((${#1} + 1))

    # Print the message to the screen
    ${ECHO} ${ECHOPARM} -e "${2}${1}"

}

boot_mesg_flush()
{
    # Reset STRING_LENGTH for next message
    STRING_LENGTH="0"
}

echo_ok()
{
    ${ECHO} -n -e "${CURS_UP}${SET_COL}${BRACKET}[${SUCCESS}  OK  ${BRACKET}]"
    ${ECHO} -e "${NORMAL}"
        boot_mesg_flush
}

echo_failure()
{
    ${ECHO} -n -e "${CURS_UP}${SET_COL}${BRACKET}[${FAILURE} FAIL ${BRACKET}]"
    ${ECHO} -e "${NORMAL}"
        boot_mesg_flush
}

echo_warning()
{
    ${ECHO} -n -e "${CURS_UP}${SET_COL}${BRACKET}[${WARNING} WARN ${BRACKET}]"
    ${ECHO} -e "${NORMAL}"
        boot_mesg_flush
}
```

Based on this LFS script:
http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.5/scripts/apds02.html

**/etc/sysconfig/modules**

```
i2c-dev
snd-soc-pcm512x
snd-soc-wm8804
snd-soc-hifiberry_dac
```

(or any module you want to load, obviously)

If there are any problems or issues with loading modules this way in a BusyBox init, I'm sure they'll end up in the comments below ;-).

Answer (score 1):

This depends on which init system you're using.  If you have Buildroot configured to use Busybox init or SysV init, then the correct way to handle this is probably through an init script.  If you have it configured to use Systemd though, you can just drop a file with a `.conf` extension in `/etc/modules-load.d/` or `/usr/lib/modules-load.d/` with each module you want loaded listed on a line by itself, and systemd will load them at boot.

Comment: Forgot to mention, it's BusyBox, i've been doing more research and that seems to be the way to go with BusyBox. Strangly I can barely find any examples of such scripts, I had expected a more 'beaten path' here ;-)

Comment: @svenema A large part of that is the design intent of busybox, they kind of expect you to build in all 'required' modules, and leave only optional things modular and then load them on-demand (either based on system configuration, or what you're actually using at the time).

Answer (score 0):

Awesome answer by @svenema! I would only like to add, that I needed to change permissions and make the `S02modules` file executable for it to work:

`chmod u+x /etc/init.d/S02modules`